# Setting gem path from ScriptEngineManager eval method

Tags: java, rubygems, jruby, javascript-engine

Is it possible to set my jruby's gem path from the ScriptEngineManager in Java? The problem is that I'm using a compressed jruby interpreter (jruby-complete.jar) and it's not possible to get this package with pre-installed gems, so what I'm trying do is running jruby from Java using the ScriptEngineManager and redirect the gem's path to the ones that I have installed on my hard drive.

Example:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer jruby = null;
        ScriptEngine runtime = null;

        try {
            runtime = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("jruby");
            jruby = new StringBuffer();

            jruby.append("require 'ruby/Libraries.rb'");
            jruby.append("\r\n");
            jruby.append("if __FILE__ == $0");
            jruby.append("\r\n");
            jruby.append("\tzkan = ZKANWritter.new(\"");
            jruby.append("G:/path/output.xls");
            jruby.append("\",\"");
            jruby.append("G:/path/kanban.txt");
            jruby.append("\",\"//path/LT CUU.tab\")");
            jruby.append("\r\n");
            jruby.append("\tzkan.write(2)");
            jruby.append("\r\n");
            jruby.append("end");

            runtime.eval(jruby.toString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

~ Eder Quiñones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just set the environment variables RUBYLIB & GEM_HOME programmatically from ruby:

```
ENV["RUBYLIB"] = "lib/libs"
ENV["GEM_HOME"] = "lib/gems"

require "library-1.rb"
...
require "library-n.rb"
```